# Distribitrion of samples in R

Tags: r

I have a large count matrix that I would like to visualise.

It contains gene IDs, sample names and abundance.

I would like to see which samples have which genes.

I did this:

```
d <- read.table("mydata")
library(reshape)
dm <- melt(d)
rn <- row.names(dm)
cn <- colnames(dm)
p = ggplot(dm, aes(x=cn, y=rn)) + stat_binhex(bins=50) + scale_fill_continuous(low="grey50", high=“blue") + p + geom_abline(slope=1, col="white") + labs(title="Sub count matrix")
```

but then I get:

> Error: unexpected input in "p = ggplot(dm, aes(x=cn, y=rn)) +

I suspect it to be because I don't assign the correct values to rn and cn.

I would like a graph that shows if the genes are present or not with x = samples and y = genes.

Mydata looks something like this: Each column is called V1, V2, V3 etc 
Each row is called the gene ID.

Example of my data: [Small clip of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeP1H.jpg)

Comment: you are using `... + p + ...` before `p` is defined

Comment: I get the same error message if I don't include + p + ?

Comment: Add a sample of your data. Than we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: hm, indeed. `cn` and `rn` should refer to columns in data in *long* format. What is your data? post a sample

Comment: You have a curly quote “ here: `high=“blue")`